# Store queried record IDs of search results for further browsing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my webapp (PHP) I have a script showing the contents of a single database record: `view.php?id=n`, where *n* is the ID of the record.

Also there are *Next* and *Previous* links on the page (to browse through the records without getting back to the record list) using the increment/decrement of the current ID to call `view.php`:

```
?id=$current_id-1 (Prev)
?id=$current_id+1 (Next)
```

Now I’m going to implement a search function. The *Next* and *Previous* links are now encouraged to guide the user through his recent search result making the mechanism above useless.

I would have to store a list of at least the IDs of the search result in the current session. Having 5000 records this means the server has to hold about 20K of data (assuming 32-bit integers) for each user doing a search query not using filters (like sorting all records by the time last changed).

Is this a proper way and acceptable in terms of performance and memory usage or are there alternative ways?

Comment: just pass the search params with next and previous buttons ! I hope I am getting you right here

Answer (score 0):

If you store only id for `prev` `next`, it is meaningless because you are getting record from db by id and probably id is primary key and indexed. However, if you want to store `key => value` pair like `ID=>value(ID)`, you can cache them not store in session. So, when user clicks `prev` or `next`, you can get result from cache by using `ID` without querying db. In this case, you need to refresh cache on each db update

Answer (score 0):

There is a data structure that is very convenient for such cases - [SplDoublyLinkedList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php). If you haven't come across linked lists, here's a good [explanation](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page165.html) with a few illustrations about them.

I'm not sure though how big their memory footprint will be, so you will want to test your mileage first. But still, they're likely to be faster than anything handmade.

Cheers.